# C# class from a SQL database table

Tags: c#, .net, orm, .net-2.0

Came across this:

http://www.eggheadcafe.com/articles/adonet_source_code_generator.asp

And wondering if this is the right solution as I am not that big of a fan of creating a class for every stored procedure or do I use Enterprise Library for ASP.net 2.0 project.

Answer (score 6):

You definitely shouldn't be creating a class for every stored procedure. There are a number of approaches you can take to handling your database interactions. You should have a good look at the major frameworks out there and decide which one best suits you. The Castle Project solution is great, and relies on nHibernate ([nHibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/343.html)). LINQ is a similar offering by Mircrosoft ([LINQ Project](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx)). Both of these solutions are full ORM frameworks (Object Relational Mapping) and will generate dynamic SQL to persist your objects in the database. Each also has it's own quirks and likes you to structure your objects in particular ways. If you don't want to manage the SQL your system uses, I would definitely recommend one of these approaches.

I come from a database background, and prefer a bit more control over my SQL. In particular I like to have my interractions handled by stored procedures. I find this enables me to control both the SQL better for optimisation, but helps me manage database security in a more friendly manner. To accommodate this approach, I recommend something like iBatis ([iBatis](http://ibatis.apache.org/)). iBatis isn't a full ORM, but rather a simple SQL mapper. The downside to my approach is that you need to write a lot more code (SQL), but I don't mind the trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any possibility of upgrading to framework 3.5? if so take a look at LINQ to SQL and Entity Framework as this will accomplish alot of this for you.

If not then as long as it generates standard code that doesnt tie you into 3rd party libraries then you could certainly use it. At my workplace we have our own generator similar to this and it works well although we will shortly be moving to LINQ to SQL.

Comment: no can do on upgrading and using LINQ To Sql. Kind of stuck with the .NEt 2.0 world.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways of wrapping a database table in a C# class; you probably want to investigate a few alternatives before choosing between the one you've linked to and the Entity Framework.

There's a software pattern called the "active record pattern" which describes exactly this approach - one C# class for each table, with load/save methods like Customer.GetById(), Customer.Save(), and so on.

For ASP.NET 2.0, check out the [Castle Project's ActiveRecord implementation](http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/index.html) and a third-party Visual Studio plugin tool called [ActiveWriter](http://altinoren.com/activewriter/) that lets you generate class wrappers for your tables using a drag'n'drop interface.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine at what point you need sets of data that are composed from your tables, and whether you want SQL to produce these with stored procedures or if your business logic layer will handle these.  As Dr8k says, nHibernate will create SQL for you, but there is a learning curve with nHibernate.  The ORM will be in control of how you are getting the data and depending on your environment and DBA's conmfort level you may other issues to overcome.

If you more comfortable with SQL, then there is another tool called [SubSonic](http://www.subsonicproject.com/) that will create wrappers ala Active Record for you while offering you the ability to use stored procedures as well.  There is also a nice query tool with a fluent interface that you can use if you are not able to use LINQ.