# Addendum to my question from yesterday: C# class from sql database

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-2.0, data-access-layer

This is my link:
[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/219986/c-class-from-a-sql-database-table)

Thought about it and this was my additional question:

Now If i am going against stored procedures, is there an easy way without using T4, LLCodeGen, Codesmith, subsonic, etc..to obtain the input/output params and types if i wanted to generate my own data access layer

This is ASP.Net 2.0

Answer (score 1):

Look into something called the Object-Relational Mappings, or ORM.  There are lots of good tools that will automate most of the data layer code for you:  NHibernate, Castle Active Record, [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/) etc.

Comment: Subsonic is open source it would provide you with an implementation for retrieving the stored procedures parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Joel Coehoorn's ORM list, you could also consider [SubSonic](http://subsonicproject.com/). I've found it to be insanely easy to use, and it supports direct access to your procs, views and tables as you deem necessary.

You'd be much better off using an existing tool rather than rolling your own code gen. (Not that you couldn't roll your own, but why reinvent the wheel -- especially with so many good options out there?)